# Cocos2dx: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "atof" referenced by "libcocos2dcpp.so"

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am trying to run my cocos2d-x game on android devices, it works perfectly on android 5.0(lollipop), but crashes on lower android versions. I am getting the following error:

02-25 10:41:09.787: E/ResourceType(18090): 0x5ad385b8: Failed to ResTable::remove() cookie = 0x3, not last table. mHeaders.size() = 4. Warning for spontaneous crashes when the garbage collector runs.
02-25 10:41:09.797: E/asset(18090): Error removing runtime skin resource (cookie 0x3)
02-25 10:41:09.797: I/asset(18090): Problem removing all runtime skin resources
02-25 10:41:09.817: D/dalvikvm(18090): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.game-2/libcocos2dcpp.so 0x418c9ce8
02-25 10:41:09.817: E/dalvikvm(18090): **dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.game-2/libcocos2dcpp.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "atof" referenced by "libcocos2dcpp.so"...**
02-25 10:41:09.817: W/dalvikvm(18090): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/game/game;
02-25 10:41:09.817: W/dalvikvm(18090): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/game/game;)
02-25 10:41:09.817: D/AndroidRuntime(18090): Shutting down VM
02-25 10:41:09.817: W/dalvikvm(18090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415af8b0)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "atof" referenced by "libcocos2dcpp.so"...
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:361)example
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at com.example.game.game.(game.java:126)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
02-25 10:41:09.827: E/AndroidRuntime(18090):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method).

I am using **cocos2d-x v2.2.6,Eclipse-Luna and android NDK r10d.**

Comment: This solution may help you. Add atof implemention by yourself.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38499898/5235238

Answer (score 5):

Try adding

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

as the first line in your Appication.mk

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem. I think a slightly better option would be to add the APP_PLATFORM := android-xx , where xx is the minSdkVersion that your app is targeting.

Answer (score 1):

Try using android NDK r9d.For cocos2dx ,Android NDK r9d is good to work.

Answer (score 1):

(I know this duplicates m0mus's earlier answer in the solution suggested, but I think the fuller explanation helps.)

Google have moved some of the C standard library functions like atof() from being inline functions in header files to normal functions. The latest NDKs will default to building a .so that is only compatible with the latest Android devices that have the atof() function in the device's standard C library (libc.so). This means if you run a library on an older device that has an older version of the C library, you will get an error loading the dll as the expected atof() function will not exist.

Have you tried setting this in your Application.mk:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

This will cause the ndk compiler to build code compatible with older Android versions.

You can also try downgrading your NDK installation to version 10b (this version predates the change where atof was moved from inline to part of libc so avoids the problem entirely).

Answer (score 0):

I am Getting it right, my current env is cocos2d-x 3.3, NDKr10d, ADT bundle (update24)

```
 log("This is A TEst for ATOF ,%f ", std::atof("1.0"));
```

[image]

Try including _GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X_ in symbols, leave values empty

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio you have to setup manually the NDK.
Go to the local.properties file of your porject and setup the ndk.dir value to the ndk directory.