# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "srand" referenced by "xx.so"

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am new to NDK develop. I have used NDK to generate `xxx.so` files and it works fine on Android 5.0 or above however it crash on Android 4.4 or pre.

**Log is:**

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "srand" referenced by "xx.so"...
>                                                          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:362)
>                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
>                                                          at com.uniquestudio.lowpoly.LowPoly.(LowPoly.java:14)
>                                                          at com.uniquestudio.lowpolyandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot load library: reloc\_library\[1285\]: cannot locate 'rand'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338318/cannot-load-library-reloc-library1285-cannot-locate-rand)

Comment: Note: not the same symbol as the dup, but is the same cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dan pointed it out in comments, your problem certainly comes from compiling against an android api level >=21.

To solve your issue, you can compile your code against the same platform than your APK's *minSdkVersion*.

How are you using the NDK? If you're using *ndk-build*, add an *Application.mk* file next to your *Android.mk* file, with for content `APP_PLATFORM:=android-14` (where 14 is your minSdkVersion).