# 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libibscanultimatejni.so' from inputs:

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I downloawed 3 .aar dependencies that are usefull to me and imported them in the libs folder of my project.

[image]

but when i try to build my project i get this error:

```
2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libibscanultimatejni.so' from inputs:
- C:\Users\SIB_ablanc\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ec6859945b3aa4b62a7fd5f11e6ab1df\transformed\jetified-inbioface-1.0.0\jni\arm64-v8a\libibscanultimatejni.so
- C:\Users\SIB_ablanc\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\73e5408d19e7af3e404ba6a3aefad870\transformed\jetified-IBSanUltimateAndroid-3.7.2\jni\arm64-v8a\libibscanultimatejni.so
If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
```

I tried to look other topics but it seems to mostly occure in reactNative project which mine isnt . Its a native android kotlin project.
Here is my build.gradle.kts file:

```
@file:Suppress("UnstableApiUsage", "DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION")

plugins {
   alias(androidlibs.plugins.application)
   alias(androidlibs.plugins.kotlin.android)
   kotlin("kapt")
   alias(androidlibs.plugins.hilt)
}

android {
   compileSdk = 32

   val getGitVersionData: () -> Map<String, Any> by extra
   val gitVersionData = getGitVersionData()
   val computedVersionCode =
       gitVersionData["Major"] as Int * 1000000 + gitVersionData["Minor"] as Int * 1000 + gitVersionData["Patch"] as Int


   defaultConfig {
       applicationId = "com.ingroupe.ees"
       minSdk = 28
       targetSdk = 32

       versionCode = computedVersionCode
       versionName = gitVersionData["FullSemVer"] as String

       testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       vectorDrawables {
           useSupportLibrary = true
       }
   }

   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
   testOptions {
       unitTests.isReturnDefaultValues = true
   }
   kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = "1.8"
   }
   buildFeatures {
       compose = true
   }
   composeOptions {
       kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.1.1"
   }
   packagingOptions {
       resources {
           excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
           excludes += "/META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors"
           pickFirsts.add("**/libibscanultimatejni.so")
           pickFirsts.add("**/libusb.so")
           //pickFirsts.add("**/*.so")
       }
   }

   signingConfigs {
       create("integration") {
           keyAlias = "integration"
           keyPassword = "INGroupeEES"
           storePassword = "INGroupeEES"
           storeFile = file("integration.jks")
       }
   }

   flavorDimensions += listOf("environment", "device")

   productFlavors {
       create("production") {
           dimension = "environment"
       }

       create("integration") {
           dimension = "environment"
           applicationIdSuffix = ".integration"

           var appCenterKey = "no key"
           try {
               appCenterKey = System.getenv("APPCENTERKEY")
           } catch (_: Throwable) {
           }

           buildConfigField("String", "appCenterKey", "\"$appCenterKey\"")

           signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("integration")
       }

       create("physicalDevice") {
           dimension = "device"
       }
       create("mockedDevice") {
           dimension = "device"
       }
   }

   buildTypes {
       debug {
           signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("integration")
       }
       release {
           isDebuggable = false
           isTestCoverageEnabled = true
           isMinifyEnabled = false
           isShrinkResources = false
           setProguardFiles(
               listOf(
                   getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                   "proguard-rules.pro"
               )
           )
       }
   }

   kapt {
       correctErrorTypes = true
   }
   hilt {
       enableAggregatingTask = false
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation(fileTree("libs"))
   /// Hilt
   implementation(androidlibs.hilt.android)
   kapt(androidlibs.hilt.compiler)
   androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.hilt.android.testing)
   androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.hilt.compiler)
   testImplementation(androidlibs.hilt.android.testing)
   testImplementation(androidlibs.hilt.compiler)

   // Kotlinx Coroutines
   implementation(androidlibs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
   testImplementation(androidlibs.kotlinx.coroutines.test)

   /// AndroidX
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.core.ktx)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.constraintlayout)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.material)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.material.icons.extended)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.activity)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.navigation.compose)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.camera.camera2)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.camera.view)
   implementation(androidlibs.androidx.camera.lifecycle)

   //Lottie
   implementation(androidlibs.airbnb.android.lottie.compose)

   //Accompanist
   implementation(androidlibs.accompanist.permissions)

   // Timber
   implementation(androidlibs.timber)

   implementation(androidlibs.coppernic.ibscanultimate)
   implementation(androidlibs.cpcCore)
   implementation(androidlibs.cpcUtilsLib)


   implementation(androidlibs.retrofit)
   implementation(androidlibs.converter.gson)
   implementation(androidlibs.converter.simplexml)
   //Accompanist
   implementation(androidlibs.accompanist.permissions)

   // App Center
   "integrationImplementation"(androidlibs.appcenter.distribute)
   "integrationImplementation"(androidlibs.appcenter.crashes)

   testImplementation(androidlibs.junit)
   androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.android.test.ext.junit)
   androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.androidx.test.espresso.core)
   androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4)
   debugImplementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui.test.manifest)
   testImplementation(androidlibs.mockito.kotlin)

   debugImplementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling)
}
```

What is this issue and how can i fix it to build my project?

Comment: Possibly related: [Use different versions of SO files in different modules in Android (like libc++_shared.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75015347/295004)